# Opera TV Browser - Play an RTMP Stream possible?

Tags: html, rss, video-streaming, rtmp

I was trying to develop a video player on the Opera TV browser but I'm not sure how to play this stream:

```
<media:content rte:start="00:46:38:880" medium="video" url="rtmpe://fmsod.rte.ie/rtevod/mp4:/2013/1121/20131121_rteone-sixnews-sixonenews_cl10225356_10225376_260_/20131121_rteone-sixnews-sixonenews_cl10225356_10225376_260__512k.mp4" type="video/mp4" rte:end="00:48:52:920" rte:server="rtmpe://fmsod.rte.ie/rtevod/" duration="134040" rte:format="content" expression="full" />
```

I get this stream information from reading an RSS feed from this location:

```
http://feeds.rasset.ie/rteavgen/player/playlist?type=iptv1&showId=10225356
```

I was able to play an mp4 video by using the html video tag but it doesn't seem to like the format above.

Has anyone any ideas?

It doesn't have to use the video tag I don't think, unless the Opera TV browser doesn't support any other methods.

Thanks in advance,
mcquaim

Comment: Anyone any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the rtmp**e** means it's encrypted and that the encryption scheme they use is Adobe specific and will only work in Flash.

Try visiting the page on something that doesn't support Flash, like an iPad, and see what video URL they use. According to the docs Opera TV does support HLS so if you can figure out how to get an HLS url you can probably make it work.